# GraniteDS websockets, same endpoint for Flex and JS

Tags: websocket, graniteds

GraniteDS [3.1.0RC1](http://www.granitedataservices.com/2014/06/25/graniteds-3-1-0-rc1-is-out/) supports Websocket JSR 356 specification. Does it mean I can use the same endpoint for Flex client and Javascript client?
I didn't find websocket demo in the GraniteDS tutorial :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)

GraniteDS implements an AMF-based messaging protocol on top of websockets.
It's not really possible nor useful to use a JS client with this same endpoint as it would not be able to communicate with Flex clients.
As for a demo/tutorial, you can have a look at [this](http://www.granitedataservices.com/2014/09/02/configuring-graniteds-websocket-support-with-flexair-applications/).